# Regex : Define a regex to catch an HTML group

Tags: html, regex

I have the following html :

```
    <div class="headNormal">
    <h1><a href="/questions/76/specify-a-mirror-when-configuring-a-gdi-environment">
    Specify a Mirror when configuring a GDI environment</a></h1></div>
```

And i'd like to catch the "Specify a Mirror when configuring a GDI environment" thing... but i'm not sure of the regex i should use for this

So far i have : `<div class="headNormal">(.*)</div>` but it doesnt give me anything.

Any help?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Not particular language, i'm just trying to do a regex for future usages.

Comment: What kind of back-end code do you use?

Generally speaking: DONT parse HTML with regex!

Comment: I know about that, but i need to parse it for future usages.

Comment: Most likely, you are not using the multiline option in your regex.  By default, `.` will not match new-lines.  You can use `[\s\S]` instead.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html  "If you parse HTML with regex you are giving in to Them and their blasphemous ways which doom us all to inhuman toil for the One whose Name cannot be expressed in the Basic Multilingual Plane, he comes."

Comment: You're not making a StackOverflow scraper, are you?  I hate those.

Comment: Thanks agent-j, it selected the block i need with this :
< div class="headNormal">([\s\S]*)< /div>

But i still don't know how to retrieve the text i need.

Comment: @Vincent S: this is easily (and more robustly) achieved with a parser.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the *exact* snippet you've provided, you'd want something like this:

```
<a .+?>(.*?)</a>
```

*However*, you're opening yourself up to a whole world of hurt if you've got to parse large HTML documents and extract the text from anchors (case-in-point is Konrad Rudolph's comment on this question). You'd be much better off with a parser.

You're not specific about the language you're using, but if it's .NET have a look at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Except that this doesn’t work when an attribute in the `<a>` tag contains a `>`. Which is legitimate.

Comment: If the snippet i provided is in a big html file, how do i find the div class=headNormal? This what i'm trying to do first.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: You're absolutely right, of course. I was basing it on the exact snippet.  The rest of the answer is probably more relevant.